# Difference between penup() and up() in turtle python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there any difference between penup() and up() in turtle python?

I used both the methods in a simple animation program and found no difference.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [both functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.penup) points to the same description, so there's no difference other than the name.

> `turtle.penup()`
>     `turtle.pu()`
>     `turtle.up()`
>
> Pull the pen up – no drawing when moving.

It's fairly unusual design for a module to expose the same functionality through multiple interfaces. This is especially true for Python since one of its design principles is "There should be one -- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it". But the `turtle` module is intended specifically for new users, so the developers must have been willing to bend the rules a little to give their audience an easier introduction to programming.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: For what it’s worth, `up` and `pu` (along with a few others) appear to be [simple aliases for the verbose name](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/turtle.py#L2472).

Comment: IMO, the two lines of code in @poke's link make it more clear that these are aliases than the documentation being repeated. My first thought on seeing all three functions being given the same documentation was "are they literally referencing the same method object?" On the other hand, source code (no matter how simple) may make the answer less accessible.

Comment: And, as an aside, I think I disagree with the developer's choice to include these aliases. I know if I was a beginning programmer, I would be wondering whether I had to use the exact counter parts, e.g. if I use `pd`, can I only use `pu`? Or could I `penup` or `up` as well? But that decision has very little to do with this question.

Comment: @JaredGoguen It was *probably* a decision made to match as many as possible other Logo/Turtle implementations.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same thing, just in different wording. `penup()` == `up()`

Answer (score 0):

penup() is the full name, and up() is what's called an alias.

An alias is what coders use to condense long functions.
Say you have *importFuncWhenClicked(object, execution file, program)*

you can condense it to something like: *importFOnClick(obj, exc, prgmFile)*